# Scala match/compare enumerations

Tags: scala

I have an enumeration that I want to use in pattern matches in an actor.  I'm not getting what i'd expect and, now, I'm suspecting I'm missing something simple.

My enumeration,

```
object Ops extends Enumeration {
  val Create = Value("create")
  val Delete = Value("delete")
}
```

Then, I create an Ops from a String:

```
val op = Ops.valueOf("create")
```

Inside my match, I have:

```
case (Ops.Create, ...)
```

But Ops.Create doesn't seem to equal ops.valueOf("create")

The former is just an atom 'create' and the later is Some(create)

Hopefully, this is enough info for someone to tell me what I'm missing...

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just trying to get a copy of `Create`, then you should refer to it directly in your code:

```
val op = Ops.Create
```

But if you are parsing it from a string, the string might contain junk, so `valueOf` returns an `Option`:

```
val op1 = Ops.valueOf("create")  // Some(Ops.Create)
val op2 = Ops.valueOf("delete")  // Some(Ops.Delete)
val op3 = Ops.valueOf("aljeaw")  // None
```

Now, in your match you can just carry along the `Option[Ops.Value]` and look for:

```
case(Some(Ops.Create),...)
```

and you have built-in robustness to junk as input.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, `Enumeration.valueOf` has been deprecated: use `withName` instead

Answer (score 1):

`Enumeration.valueOf` returns `None` or `Some`, because you may be asking to create a value that doesn't exist. In your case, for example, `Ops.valueOf("blah")` would return `None`, since you don't have an appropriate enumeration value.

To be honest, in this case, I'd use a [case class](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/107) or a [case object](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/08/enumerations.html) instead of an `Enumeration` (they provide better type safety).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like I needed to use the 'get' method of the returned Some to actually get what I wanted.  E.g.

```
ops.valueOf("create").get == Ops.Create
```

Seems neither intuitive nor friendly but it works.

Comment: It's because `Enumeration.valueOf` returns an `Option` object, which means you have to use `get` to get the value value.